# OrderFilter (Sorting) by Virtual Property API-Platform

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

```
    class SingleProduct extends AbstractEntity implements SingleProductEntityInterface
    {

        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @Groups({"read", "get"})
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         *  @Groups({"read", "get"})
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="main_han", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
         * @Groups({"read","get"})
         */
        private $mainHan;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="main_ean", type="string", length=13, nullable=true)
         * @Groups({"read","get"})
         */
        private $mainEan;

       /**
       * @Groups({"read","get"})
       */

       private $nbCatalogs;

    }
```

In this entity, I am taking count of relational entity in getter of nbCatalogs. Other above fields are columns in database. when I added

```
@ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, properties={"id", "name","mainHan","mainEan","nbCatalogs"}, arguments={"orderParameterName"="order"})
```

I am able to sort asc and desc by id,name,mainHan,mainEan but I am not able to sort by virtual property which I created 'nbCatalogs'.
How can I achieve sorting by property nbCatalogs??

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by virtual property?  How should API platform know how to sort?

Comment: @StephanVierkant  I am not the OP but I am facing similar thing. Imagine you have Orders which have appointments and those appointments have some procedures. Our client would like to see, how many appointments does each procedure have. In a denormalizer, I added $procedure['orderedXtimes'] = count($procedure->appointments());   But our client also wants to sort procedures by the most times ordered. AFAIK sorting works only on database level, so i can sort by name, date,... but not by relational child count, same as I cant return count of relational children, just list of children.

Comment: @StephanVierkant so the "virtual property" means basically a count of children in a OneToMany relationship, that can be added only in denormalizer, which is called after the results are already fetched from database.